# How to restart/relaunch application programatically if it crashes in Android?

Tags: android

I would like to know whether there is a way to **Relaunch/Restart an application programatically** in Android if it crashes.Suppose if the application crashes due to some error I want it to restart automatically.Can you let me know how to do this?

Answer (score 5):

First of all, your application shouldn't crash. If it does crash, it's usually due to an uncaught exception (NullPointerException, usually). Figure out where the exception is being thrown and fix it.

As for your question, specifically, you can also catch these exceptions and prevent the app from crashing. For example, this would prevent a NullPointerException from crashing the application:

```
try {
    Object nullObj = null;
    if (nullObj.toString().equals("bleh")) {
        // app should crash from the NullPointerException if uncaught
    }
} catch (NullPointerException e) {
    // Catch the NullPointerException and prevent crashing
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

In this case, the app does not crash and continues displaying the app. Instead of restarting the application at this point, perhaps you should just jump back to the previous Activity and let the user know something went wrong.

Comment: +1 its all about anticipating and reacting correctly to failures.

Answer (score 0):

I understand your plight. Catching all exceptions before release is going to be tough. In event of a crash, you could use [ACRA](http://code.google.com/p/acra/) to capture the exception - this would avoid the force close. It also has mechanisms to restart the app I believe.